# Filter headlines using tags

Tags: org-mode, tags, sparse-tree

Is there a **fast** method to select an 1-level headlines subtree?

I have the following annotations and I want to select only all the headlines with the ":NOTES:" TAG and copy them to the *NOTES* buffer:

```
* Title 1 :NOTES:
bla bla bla

* Title 2 :NONOTES:
bla bla bla

* Title 3 :NOTES:OTHER:
bla bla bla


* Title 4 :NONOTES:
bla bla bla
```

what I want to get in the *NOTES* buffer is:

```
* Title 1 :NOTES:
bla bla bla

* Title 3 :NOTES:OTHER:
bla bla bla
```

... although it seems like a very trivial problem, I was able to find only very complicated solutions!

Thanks for any suggestion!

*edit* To perform this filtering operation and filtered buffer creation I use the following piece of code

```
(defun my-org-select-headlines-with-tag (tag)
  "Select all headlines with the specified tag in the current
   buffer using org-map-entries function; after selecting them,
   create a new org-mode buffer with title tag+'-sparse-tree' and
   copy into the sparsetree-buffer all headlines with the
   specified tag found with their body."
  (interactive "sTag: ")
  (let ((sparse-tree-buffer (generate-new-buffer (concat tag "-sparse-tree"))))
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (when (member tag (org-get-tags))
         (let ((headline-string (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
               (body-string (org-get-entry)))
           (with-current-buffer sparse-tree-buffer
             (insert headline-string "\n" body-string "\n\n"))))))
    (switch-to-buffer sparse-tree-buffer)
    (org-mode)))
```

Comment: `-` is not a legal character for a tag (try `_` instead or get rid of `-` altogether) and every tag has to have a `:` at each end, so you need one after the last tag, which is missing after the `OTHER` tag i: `:NOTES:OTHER:` - see [Org syntax](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Headings) although the doc is missing the fact that `TAGS` needs to be enclosed in colons as well.

Comment: You can use `C-c / m +NOTES` to create a sparse tree of headlines with the selected tag(s), but I'm not quite sure how to deal with that next: supposedly, exporting the visible portion only (`C-c C-e C-v O O` would create an Org mode buffer with just the sparse tree, but I could not make it work - see [Sparse Trees](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-Trees.html) in the manual.

Comment: I had also tried that method (although in my "standard" Emacs there is no org-mode to org-mode exporter) and had seen that it did not work; you cannot even copy and paste just the selected subtree. Since the purpose of using TAG is just to be able to filter the headlines, it seems a bit unbelievable to me all this difficulty

Comment: *Copying* subtrees from one file to another is not a common operation: that creates two places with the same information so you have to worry about syncing the two  - it's better to have a single source of truth. BTW, why do you want to do that? You might expand your question and add your motivation. It may be that there is another way to do what you ultimately want to do. But I'm not sure whether there is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. You might want to ask the question on the [Org mode  ML](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode) if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: I often use a single org-mode file to take annotations (quotes, ideas, some chunk code, a funny tweet, etc.); I usually add a tag to the annotation and a timestamp; imagine you wanted to create an org file just with quotes or just with scripts in Perl or Python using tags: how would you do it?

Comment: I would use `org-map-entries` to find the headings of interest and `org-refile` to move (or copy - but I explained about why I think copying is not such a good idea) them to another place. But I haven't tried it so I don't know what difficulties I might run into ATM.

Answer (score 1):

[Incorporating comments into the answer to make it as complete as possible]

You can use `C-c / m +NOTES` to create a sparse tree of headlines with the selected tag(s), but I'm not quite sure how to deal with that next: supposedly, exporting the visible portion only (`C-c C-e C-v O O` would create an Org mode buffer with just the sparse tree, but I could not make it work - see [Sparse Trees](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-Trees.html) in the manual. Whether that's because I am not doing things correctly or because there is a bug is not clear: it needs further investigation.

---

Here's an implementation of "selecting by tag and copying selected subtrees to another file", using `org-map-entries` and `org-refile` as mentioned in my (later) comment:

```org
* Title 1                                                                                                        :NOTES:
blue bla bla

** foo
foo

** bar
bar

* Title 2                                                                                                     :NONOTES:
bla bla bla

** baz
baz

* Title 3                                                                                                  :NOTES:OTHER:
bla bla bla

** hunoz
hunoz

* Title 4                                                                                                     :NONOTES:
bla bla bla


* Code

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer

    (defun my/refile-notes ()
      ;; only top-level headlines need apply
      (when (= (nth 1 (org-heading-components)) 1)
        (org-refile 3 nil '("Refiled" "/tmp/notes.org" nil 0))))

    (let ((org-reverse-note-order nil))
      (org-map-entries #'my/refile-notes "+NOTES" 'file)
      nil)
#+end_src
```

I added a few second level headlines to your example and then added the `Code` section. This includes a code block that you can run by typing `C-c C-c` somewhere in it. Before you do that, you should prepare the `notes.org` file that will accept the refiles. I made a `/tmp/notes.org` file that looks like this:

```org
* Refiled
```

and I refile under the headline at position 0. After running the code block, the `notes.org` file looks like this:

```org
* Refiled
** Title 1                                                                                                       :NOTES:
blue bla bla

*** foo
foo

*** bar
bar

** Title 3                                                                                                 :NOTES:OTHER:
bla bla bla

*** hunoz
hunoz
```

which is not quite what you want: there is the headline that I have to use to refile under and the subtrees are now at level 2, rather than at the top level; but that's easy to fix: select the region from `Title 1` to the end and say `M-<left>` (i.e. press the `Meta` key and while holding it down, press the Left arrow key) - that will promote all the level-2 trees to the top level. If you want to, you can also delete the first line (the `Refiled` heading), but you'd have to put it back before you can run the code block again; otherwise, the second time around, everything is going to be refiled under the `Title 1` subtree.

---

The code block uses `org-map-entries`, a very powerful mapping function that takes a function as argument and applies that function on every headline that matches. In this particular case, we match headlines with a `NOTES` tag and apply the function `my/refile-notes` to each such headline. The `my/refile-notes` function selects only top-level headlines and runs `org-refile` on them. The `3` argument makes it copy the entries, rahter than moving them, and the RFLOC argument (the list `("Refiled" "/tmp/notes.org" nil 0)`) tells refile where to refile: under the "Refiled" headline at position 0 in the `/tmp/notes.org` file.

The reason that `my/refile-notes` specifically selects top level headlines is that tags are (usually) inherited, so lower level headlines like `foo` and `bar` under the `Title 1` headline would *also* match the tag and would be refiled a second time. Another way to proceed would be to turn off tag inheritance and then not worry about checking the level:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
    (defun my/refile-notes ()
      (org-refile 3 nil '("Refiled" "/tmp/notes.org" nil 0)))

    (let ((org-reverse-note-order nil)
          (org-use-tag-inheritance nil))
      (org-map-entries #'my/refile-notes "+NOTES" 'file)
      nil)
#+end_src
```

Now only headlines with an explicit `NOTES` tag will match. I probably would go with this implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions; if you look above, I had posted the code of the elisp function with which I solve the headline filter problem; however, I wanted to find out if there is an already implemented method (which I do not know) __WITHIN__ org-mode for filtering headlines; if you click on a tagA here on this site, you get a list of the questions tagged with that tagA: for me, this is the 'natural' behaviour of tags

Comment: There is a filtering suggesion in the comment: use `C-c / m`. The problem is that you want to operate on the filtered subset and copy it to another file. That's what the answer provides and even though it is not built-in, it is simple enough  to add to your original file and do the filtering with a simple `C-c C-c` on a code block. IOW, it is *almost* built-in. After all, Emacs is extensible for a reason: not everything that everyone needs is built in, but almost everything can be implemented (with various degrees of difficutly).