# org-mode, tags based Dynamic Headings

Tags: org-mode

I have a bunch of headings scattered around with certain tags.

Is there any way to create a subheading that is somehow a result of all these headings?

I want to eventually export such a subheading to html.

EDIT: Here's an example

I have a project that needs some power tools to be bought, so I will send a list of items to buy to the shop.

In my tools file, I have a few headings with power tools tagged :projecta:. These headings are scattered around the file tool.org

I want to somehow make a subheading where these headings that include the tag :projecta: appears. That way, I can export this subheading to html which I can send to the shop.

EDIT 2: I picture this as a query, which results in some kind of created buffer, so that I can export it.

EDIT 3: Programmatically, this would then be solved like scanning a set of files and extract the headings that contains the tag :projecta: along with their contents and put it into a new buffer.

Comment: My best answer here would be: YES, probably this is possible. However, it is not clear what you want and why you want this. Could you add some context and/or provide some example? Also, maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks!

Comment: You are not specifying whether you want the heading to *move* to the subheading (BTW, subheading of what?), or whether you want a "virtual" collection of some sort, with the headings remaining in their original places. `org-refile` is the answer in the first case; I don't know how to do the second case (maybe a sparse tree, but [last time I tried](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77118/14825) I couldn't make it work. See [Sparse trees](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-Trees.html) in the manual.)

Comment: Actually, `org-refile` can *copy* the relevant headings to another file, leaving the original headings untouched. It seems to be exactly what you need for what you describe in EDIT 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example file `tools.org` with a couple of code blocks that implement the `org-refile` strategy in the comments:

```el
* foo                                                                                                         :projecta:
foo

* bar
bar

* baz                                                                                                         :projecta:
baz

* one
one

* two
two

* three                                                                                                       :projecta:
three


* Code                                                                                                        :noexport:

#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/refile ()
    (let* ((org-refile-keep t)
           (org-reverse-note-order nil)
           (refile-target-file "/tmp/tools-projecta.org")   ; adjust the path to your needs
           (rfloc `("Tools to order" ,refile-target-file nil 1)))
      (org-refile nil nil rfloc)))

  (defun my/refile-by-tag ()
    (org-map-entries #'my/refile "+projecta" 'file))

#+end_src

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (my/refile-by-tag)
#+end_src
```

Before you run the code blocks, create an output file `tools-projecta.org` with a single headline at the very beginning of the file:

```
* Tools to order
```

Now run the first code block with `C-c C-c` in order to define the function `my/refile-by-tag` and then run the second code block with `C-c C-c` in order to run the function. That will refile (by copying - it does not affect the original file) the three `:projecta:`-tagged entries to `tools-projecta.org` which you can then export to HTML.

The `my/refile-by-tag` function works by scanning all the headlines that match the `:projecta:` tag, using `org-map-entries` for the scan, and applying the `my/refile` function on each headline that matches. The `my/refile` function then calculates a refile location `rfloc` and calls `org-refile` with that location. It locally sets `org-refile-keep` to `t` for the duration of the `org-refile` call: that makes `org-refile` copy, rather than move, the entries. It also makes sure that `org-reverse-note-order` is nil: `org-map-entries` scans from top to bottom for the entries that match and that setting makes sure that `org-refile` refiles them in the same order.

Comment: ... and another question, another answer and more ... crickets.